# PHP Crashing on PDO Statement Prepare

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, crash

I'm working on a site with registration/login capabilities. I've got a sign-up php file which just holds the sign-up form and posts the variables. Then I've got a functions file which connects to the database (this was done in an external file but I moved it to make troubleshooting simpler), a function which validates the form input (everything is filled in, password is relatively secure), makes sure there are no current users with the email this user has provided, and then attempts to register. The sign-up form just runs the `signUpSubmit()` function on post.

The problem is that it crashes as soon as I attempt to prepare a statement. The code below works mostly. If I enter invalid data in the form (don't type a fairly secure password, don't fill something in), it throws the error just fine. If I run it with the code to check for a user that already has this email commented, it works fine, just takes you back to the signup page. If, however, I uncomment even the first line of the commented code below (`$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM`users`WHERE email = :email");`), it just loads a blank page, as if there's some kind of syntax error. It must be connecting to the database properly, as if I mess up my username or password for the connection it DOES throw an error, where there's none if everything is set correctly. I'm really baffled here.

```
<?php
//include_once 'db_connect.php';

session_start();

$DB_host = "localhost";
$DB_user = "root";
$DB_pass = "password";
$DB_name = "database";

try
{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};dbname={$DB_name}",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

function signUpSubmit() { // Validates inputs (makes sure they're all filled in, email has valid email, 
                            //  password has password that's relatively secure. Email and email 
                            //  confirmation and password and password confirmation match. Then
                            //  checks if the user already exists.
    if(empty($_POST['first_name'])) {
        $firstNameError = "<span style='color: red'>*Please enter your first name.</span><br />";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['last_name'])) {
        $lastNameError = "<span style='color: red'>*Please enter your last name.</span><br />";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $emailError = "<span style='color: red'>*Please enter your email.</span><br />";
    } else if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $emailError = "<span style='color: red'>*Email Address not valid.</span><br />";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['email_confirm'])) {
        $emailConfirmError = "<span style='color: red'>*Please confirm your email.</span><br />";
    } else if ($_POST['email'] != $_POST['email_confirm']) {
        $emailConfirmError = "<span style='color: red'>*Email addresses do not match.</span><br />";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $passwordError = "<span style='color: red'>*Please enter your password.</span><br />";
    } else { // Validate password has one uppercase and one lowercase letter, 
                //  1 numer, at least 8 characters
        $passwordError = "<span style='color: red'>*";

        if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 8) {
            $passwordError = $passwordError . "Password must be at least 8 characters long. ";
        }
        if(!preg_match('/[a-z]/', $_POST['password'])){
            $passwordError = $passwordError . "Password must contain at least 1 lowercase letter. ";
        }
        if(!preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $_POST['password'])){
            $passwordError = $passwordError . "Password must contain at least 1 uppercase letter. ";
        }
        if(!preg_match('/[0-9]/', $_POST['password'])){
            $passwordError = $passwordError . "Password must contain at least 1 number. ";
        }

        $passwordError = $passwordError . "</span><br />";

        if($passwordError == "<span style='color: red'>*</span><br />") {
            $passwordError = "";   
        }
    }
    if(empty($_POST['password_confirm'])) {
        $passwordConfirmError = "<span style='color: red'>*Please confirm your password.</span><br />";
    } else if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password_confirm']) {
        $passwordConfirmError = "<span style='color: red'>*Passwords do not match.</span><br />";   
    }

    // Add all the errors generated into an array to return
    $errors = array($firstNameError, $lastNameError, $emailError, $emailConfirmError, $passwordError, $passwordConfirmError); 

    if(!array_filter($errors)) { // There were no errors, check if there is already
                                    // a user with this email address
        /*$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE email = :email");  
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch();

        if($row['email'] == $_POST['email']) { // If a user with this email address exists, return an error
            $emailError = "<span style='color: red'>*Email Address already taken. Please choose another.</span><br />";
            $errors = array($firstNameError, $lastNameError, $emailError, $emailConfirmError, $passwordError, $passwordConfirmError); 
        } else { // Register the user
            if(register($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) { // Registration successful
                redirect("index.php?signed-up=1");
            } else { // Registration failed
                redirect("index.php?signed-up=0");
            }
        }*/
    } else {
        return $errors;   // Return errors
    }
}

function register($first_name, $last_name, $email, $password)
{
    $new_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(first_name, last_name, email, password) 
                                               VALUES(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password)");

    $stmt->bindparam(":first_name", $first_name);
    $stmt->bindparam(":last_name", $last_name);
    $stmt->bindparam(":email", $email); 
    $stmt->bindparam(":password", $new_password);                                         

    if($stmt->execute()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;   
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling error reporting or checking any of your error logs to see if php is complaining about anything instead of getting a blank screen?

Comment: You are not passing your `$db` into your regiser function that I can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `redirect()` function might not exist and thus give you problems.

Another thing I noticed is you are trying to access $db from inside your functions there. They won't see the variable due to differences in scope. That actually might be the cause.

Comment: The redirect function I just didn't think to include in the code example but it is there. Alas! You are a gentleperson and a scholar, for it was in fact just the scope of the $db variable. Just passed the function that when I called it and now it works just fine. Thanks!